# how to pass list values containing dictionaries as values while pass from the command line

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

```
    python3 2.py "[{'a':'1','a':'11',},{'b':'2','b1':'22',},{'c':'3','c1':'33',}]"
```

gives me the below output. I want to parse each value of the list one by one using for loop
print(sys.argv[1])
<class 'str'>

```
    #i want print each value of that list 
    
    #for example: 
    
    
    a = sys.argv[1];
    for i in a:
        print(i) 
    
    
    
    # output should be 
    {'a':'1','a':'11',} 
    {'b':'2','b1':'22',}
    {'c':'3','c1':'33',}
```

Comment: If you trust the person operating this script, you can [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) the string to parse it into a list that you can then iterate over. Note, however, that `eval` will also execute arbitrary Python code for people with malicious intent, so take precautions if your plan on using that somewhere in the www where anyone can access it

Comment: Use JSON to pass arguments, then json.loads(your_argv_here)

Comment: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in one loop by searching the **string** until I found a **dictionary** ("{"), then finding the end of the dictionary ("}"), and plugging these values into python's **substring builder** like so: `str[start:end]` Then this process repeats, but it only searches the text after the text we have already searched.
This *should* work with any list of dictionaries.

```
a = sys.argv[1]
end = 0 # The end of previous dictionary ('}')

for i in range(a.count('{')):
    print(a[a.find('{', end, len(a)): a.find('}', end, len(a))+1])
    end = a.find('}', end, len(a))+1
```

Here are some examples of input/output:

```
Input: (your example)
>python test.py "[{'a':'1','a':'11',},{'b':'2','b1':'22',},{'c':'3','c1':'33',}]"

Output:
{'a':'1','a':'11',}
{'b':'2','b1':'22',}
{'c':'3','c1':'33',}


Input:
>python test.py "[{'b' : '2','b2' : '22','b3' : 'wow'},{'c' : '3','c1' : '33',},{'e' : 'yay!','e2' : 'it works!'}]"

Output:
{'b' : '2','b2' : '22','b3' : 'wow'}
{'c' : '3','c1' : '33',}
{'e' : 'yay!','e2' : 'it works!'}
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, of course, but this solution works very well.

Comment: you are correct. I think i have stated the question wrong i guess so
```
 "[{
        "a": "name",
        "b": "age",
    },
    {
        "a1": "name1",
        "b1": "age1",
    },
]"
```
I am trying to pass this, i am getting a new lines and extra spaces, how can i avoid that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have created a new question try to solve if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394798/passing-list-of-dictionary-as-command-line-argument